# Generate Ajax data string in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays. One for that contains keys and the other that contains input values, like so:

```
var keys   = ['id', 'name', 'category'];
var values = ['1', 'nameVal', 'catVal'];
```

Now what I'm trying to do is create a data string using a **loop** to use for a jQuery Ajax function:

```
var dataString = 'id=1&name=nameVal&category=catVal'; 

$.ajax({
    data: dataString,
    ...
});
```

So I tried writing a function like so:

```
function generateDataString(keys, values, ID)
{
    var dataString = 'id=' + ID;

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) 
    {
        var dataString += '&' + SOMETHINGHERE + '=' + values[i];
    }

    return dataString;
}
```

I have already pushed `values` in the `for` loop, but where it says **SOMETHINGHERE**, I need to get the keys too.

I've also used the `+=` operator which I assume is the correct way to go about this, however I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong and how I can also use the `key` in the `dataString`?

If it's easier to use jQuery to achieve this, then that's perfectly fine too

Comment: Try using `dataString += '&' + SOMETHINGHERE + '=' + values[i];` without `var`

Comment: when using `var` you are defining the local variable, not changing the parent function variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get rid of the var inside the for loop.

```
var keys   = ['id', 'name', 'category'];
var values = ['1', 'nameVal', 'catVal'];

 var dataString = 'id=' + '28';

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) 
    {
       dataString += '&' + keys[i] + '=' + values[i];
    }

alert(dataString);
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fLo65noL/

I modify your SOMETHINGHERE with keys[i] and i assume that your ID is 28.

And you will have something like: `id=28&id=1&name=nameVal&category=catVal`

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought I had to use another `for` loop of some sort to get `keys[i]` but obviously not :)

Comment: If you have the same number of values and keys this will work good.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
var dataString += '&' + SOMETHINGHERE + '=' + values[i];
```

With:

```
dataString += '&' + SOMETHINGHERE + '=' + values[i];
```

You can't "add" to a variable you're declaring. (That declaration shouldn't be there in the first place)

Comment: @Lodder: Time to take a break ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is the fact you have a `var` on that line. Remove the `var`.

BUT There is no need to generate the string, use an object.

```
var keys   = ['id', 'name', 'category'];
var values = ['1', 'nameVal', 'catVal'];

var data = {};
for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    data[keys[i]] = values[i];
}

$.ajax({
    data: data,
    ...
});
```

In reality there is no need to have the two arrays, just have the object to start.

```
var data = {
   'id' : "1",
   'name' : "nameVal",
   'category': "catVal"
};
```

Comment: The 2 arrays are generated via the dynamics of the way the page work (too long to go into). But thanks for the comment about the object.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code cause the problem

```
 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) 
    {
        var dataString += '&' + SOMETHINGHERE + '=' + values[i]; // This one
    }
```

What you are trying to do here is that you want to declare variable "dataString" but when you it's created, append some string to variable content.

You have delared variable before the loop, so there is no need to redeclare it again with each step in the loop, especially if you want to append some string with each step.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) 
    {
        dataString += '&' + SOMETHINGHERE + '=' + values[i]; // This one
    }
```